# How to activate an EditText field on a newly added item in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of items held in a `RecyclerView`. Now, these items each have an `EditText` view in them.

I'd like to activate (set focus to) the `EditText` of an item when it's added the first time. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the relevant view, keep a reference to the newly added item in the adapter and when it's view is bound, call `view.requestFocus()` (see the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus())).

Comment: Where should I call it, given that the view is in a RecyclerView?

Comment: How do you add the view to the RecyclerView? (could add that code to your question?)

Comment: The usual way, with an adapter. There's no really other way of doing it..?

Comment: ok, when you add your item to your adapter, keep a ref to the dataitem / a tag / idx in your data-container / another identifier in your adapter, when binding the viewholder for the new element, call `requestFocus`?

Comment: I did something like that and got it working. Could you edit your answer to contain a full answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

To get focus and show the keyboard you would write something like this:

```
if(myEditText.requestFocus()) {
   getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}
```

You need to clear focus if another EditText gets focus. This can be done with

```
myEditText.clearFocus()
```

Take note, that all the EditText views should have set their onFocusChangeListener to the same listener

Comment: How do I know which EditText is the newly added one?